# How do I write a regex to match a string that doesn't contain a word?

Tags: c#, regex, regex-negation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Regular expression to match string not containing a word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-string-not-containing-a-word)

To not match a set of characters I would use e.g. `[^\"\\r\\n]*`

Now I want to not match a fixed character set, e.g. "|="

In other words, I want to match: ( not ", not \r, not \n, and not |= ).

**EDIT:** I am trying to modify the regex for parsing data separated with delimiters. The single-delimiter solution I got form [a CSV parser](http://www.hotblue.com/article0000.aspx?a=0006), but now I want to expand it to include multi-character delimiters. I do not think lookaheads will work, because I want to consume, not just assert and discard, the matching characters.

Comment: @George, how is this an exact duplicate? Yes, both are resolved with negative lookaheads, but mine required multiple matching sequences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, it should be: `((?![\"\\r\\n]|[|][=]).)*`

The full regex, modified from the CSV parser link in the original post, will be: `((?<field>((?![\"\\r\\n]|[|][=]).)*)|\"(?<field>([^\"]|\"\")*)\")([|][=]|(?<rowbreak>\\r\\n|\\n|$))`

This will match any amount of characters of ( not ", not \r, not \n, and not |= ), or a quoted string, followed by ( "|=" or end of line )